# How do I specify the order that Network-Manager populates /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: rhel, dns, networkmanager, resolv.conf

Network Manager is posting the correct name servers and search domains into /etc/resolv.conf when I restart the network.  However, it is not in an order I like.  How can I tell Network Manager to prioritize the nameservers and search domain information of a certain interface over another?

Example:

What I get:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search silatria.org relinq.org pripylen.org acarime.org
nameserver 120.052.0.2
nameserver 120.052.0.1
nameserver 10.66.66.1
```

What I want

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search acarime.org silatria.org relinq.org pripylen.org 
nameserver 10.66.66.1  
nameserver 120.052.0.2
nameserver 120.052.0.1
```

acarime.org & nameserver 10.66.66.1 belongs to my network interface enp3s0
120.052.0.2.1, 120.052.0.1 & silatria.org relinq.org pripylen.org belongs to my network interface enp4s0

Comment: It would be nice to have the version of rhel / `rpm -q NetworkManager` here, e.g. just in case there's a feature for it but it was added later.

Answer (score 13):

Set `ipv4.dns-priority` of at least one of the profiles, to specify the relative order.

For example

```
nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" ipv4.dns-priority 5
```

and reactivate the connection.

See the manual [nm-settings(5)](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings-nmcli.html) for details.

Comment: You're my hero of the day. 3 hours today and a multiple of that on others that ended in aahhh F....It...

Comment: I had to use: `.. +ipv4.dns-priority 5` (with +, otherway it breaks my wireguard)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work.
The nameserver used in the lab still have no priority over the ISP ones that are automatically added to `/etc/resolv.conf` first.

The only way to do this is to disable `/etc/resolv.conf` update by NetworkManager and switch either to **Wicked** and modify the interface file for each dns server in the wanted order; OR modify the `/etc/sysconfig/network/config` Directive **NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY=** to "STATIC" AND furnish the static DNS list with the directive **NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS=** with the DNS in your wanted order.

The issue is: with this kind of settings NetworkManager is no more usable as the different profile's DNS list are not added to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

I can't understand why NetworkManager can not be configured as Wicked interface.

```
DNS1= mydns
DNS2= ispdns1
DNS3= ispdns2
```

I did not found any directive telling the ISP dns servers to be added at the end of the list instead of the top...

What I did after read again the documentation: for a laptop there is two files to be modified:

- /etc/dhclient.conf
- /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

*First* looking at **dhclient.conf** you have to be sure to uncomment those two lines:

- prepend domain-name-servers <Your DNS here or 127.0.0.1>;
- require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;

If you are using a particular DNS (in my case I handle my own zone with a DNS) you have to write something like

```
prepend domain-name-servers 192.168.0.3;
```

If not, default is

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

Second, looking at **NetworkManager.conf** you have to write something like this:

```
[main]
plugins=keyfile
dns=default
rc-manager=file
dhcp=dhclient

[connectivity]
uri=http://conncheck.opensuse.org

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

...and never forget to commit

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

...and `more /etc/resolv.conf` to see if it has worked as expected ^^

```
rasalgethi:/etc/NetworkManager # more /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search dezordi.world
nameserver 192.168.0.3
nameserver 62.197.111.140
nameserver 109.88.203.3
```

These settings could also be relevant for workstations, but they are less likely to be moved from physical networks to others.